# How do I detect a keypress event with PyAutoGUI?

Tags: python-2.7, pyautogui

How do I use PyAutoGUI to detect a keypress event? In my research, I could not make an example in this model:

```
import pyautogui

num = 0
if pyautogui.press('b'): # I know the right thing is not to use the press, but, what do I put in place?
    num = 1
```

Answer (score 14):

Detecting keystrokes isn't possible in PyAutoGUI. You might want to try the Pynput module instead: https://pypi.org/project/pynput/

Answer (score 11):

The python [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) library provides the exact function you need:

```
import keyboard

if keyboard.is_pressed('b'):
    num = 1
```

Comment: `keyboard` lib uses MIT license compared to GPL of `pynput`. But beware that in `keyboard` lib (a) "the Linux parts reads raw device files (/dev/input/input*) but this requires root" and (b) OS X support is experimental.